# Javascript Array save into mySQL Database as BLOB (MIME TEXT not IMAGE)!

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays, blob

I was looking for an example how to store a large text array ( javascript ) into my mySQL Database as BLOB.

I don´t know which solution works:

> 1. Javascript array will be send via Ajax JSON then processed via the PHP File.
>      Convert JSON -> BLOB and save into mySQL Database.
>      Fetching BLOB convert to JSON send to javascript variable.
> 2. Create a BLOB with arraydata and send a BLOB file via Ajax ( possible? ) and store it in
>      the database. Fetching Blob via Ajax converting it in javascript back to an array.

It would really help me if somehow has some tutorials regarding this question.
I have seen some rough examples for saving images (MIME: Type PNG etc) but not MIME: Type Text.

Thank you !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Already solved it.
Question closed.

I just base64_encoded and base64_decoded the variable as usual.
You just had to assure that in the my.ini (mySQL) max_packet size was set larger than 1MB in order to save the file, that was the reason it was not working.